# Clone a locally mounted repository

Tags: git, clone

I keep my bare repositories on an AFS file server, mounted locally.
When I clone them, I do

```
git clone --no-hardlinks file:///afs/whereever.foo.bar/myrepository.git
```

I frequently get the following:

```
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

and no files.  This is easily fixed with

```
git branch master origin/master  
git checkout master
```

but I was wondering how to fix it so this isn't necessary.

Thanks,
Liam

Comment: You say "frequently", but does that happen all the time, or just sometimes? What if you don't use `--no-hardlinks`?

Comment: Greg, shouldn't `--no-hardlinks` have no effect, anyway, given it's a different filesystem?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but you never know. If it doesn't work when `--no-hardlinks` is used in that situation, maybe there's a bug somewhere.

Comment: I know "frequently" is kind of vague; it's happened several times and I haven't figured out what the common trait is when it happens.  I just tried without --no-hardlinks on a particular repository that was giving me this error, and it still gives me the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the `/afs/whereever.foo.bar/myrepository.git/HEAD` file.

Comment: OK I've checked it. It referred to a non-master branch, apparently one that doesn't exist anymore (I recognize the name as one I used at one point, but it's not in there anymore). So I changed that to ref: refs/heads/master and now the repository clones just fine, no error. So my next question is, how did that end up in HEAD instead of refs/heads/master? Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: It's hard to tell now, there's a plenty of ways you could've set that.