# git Warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout

Tags: git, gitosis

I'm trying to setup gitosis according to the instructions [here](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way).

It works fine from my remote machine so the server seems to be setup fine but I'd also like to be able to do development on my gitosis server machine from a different user account (not the git user created in the gitosis setup).

I've copied the key and modified the gitosis.conf so that the other user account has access but when I try to clone it seems to work except at the end it says:

```
git Warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout
```

and I end up with an empty directory except for .git

I've google for this a bit but have no real insight into what the problem is

Comment: For those who ran into this problem with GitHub and took the first Hit on Google, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/how-do-i-change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master and https://help.github.com/articles/error-remote-head-refers-to-nonexistent-ref-unable-to-checkout

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found out what was going wrong.  The problem was that I wasn't paying attention to the warnings when I was pushing to my gitosis server so I didn't realize that I wasn't pushing a particular branch.  I had assumed it would just push the current but that isn't the case until you set:

```
git config push.default current
```

Comment: This is the post that tipped me off to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475468/git-push-failed-you-did-not-specify-any-refspecs-to-push and the fact that when I did git branch -r based on Michael Krelin's answer and got nothing back.

Comment: Thanks for this post. I guess the part I am not understanding is where you are when you are doing this. I get the head error as well but I am not sure where you doing the git config push.default current

Answer (score 22):

1. Do the `git branch -r` and `git checkout -b master <remotebranchofinterest>`
2. Check the `HEAD` file in remote .git.
3. Check if somebody already asked the question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959989/clone-a-locally-mounted-repository/1960001#1960001)

Answer (score 18):

One more possible cause for this warning might be that the `master` branch in the repository is missing (OR) the repository does NOT use a master branch. If this is the case, just don't worry about the Warning!, use

```
git checkout <some_existing_branch>
```

The warning is because, by default, after the pull git tries to checkout into the master branch.

Comment: This is a problem for me right now. If you're using pip to install Python packages from git, it seems git tries to checkout master first, then switches to whatever branch or commit you ask it to. The first step will fail if you don't have master in the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem. It seems that on my first push I did `git push origin master:/refs/heads/master` instead of `git push origin master:refs/heads/master` (notice the extra slash). This caused my master to be placed (in the remote repository) at `refs/heads/refs/heads/master` instead of `refs/heads/master`. The fix was to reorganize the folders on remote and re-push.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. Add to gitosis authorization and SSH key for the user account on your server and clone as usual:

```
user@server$ git clone git@server:repo.git
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did and that resulted in the error message.  Access appears to be fine based on the git output (I enabled debugging to give me more insight).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to clone over `http://` note that you need a git newer than 1.6.6 - otherwise you should use a `git://` based URI.

Answer (score 0):

I use tortoiseGit and I'm not aware of how to use git via the command line. So I always wonder how I can avoid such problem in my tortoise. So maybe I am not alone. I fixed the problem this way:

- clone the remote repo
- right click on the root folder and from there choose an existing branch

Im my case, there was only a branch "dev", without master. So when I tried to clone there was no local branch to check out and as soon as I switched to "dev" it was able to check out all the content successfully. Hope that will be helpful.